# Why would views not render with .el?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've finally got my Rails Todo List app to display the Todos using Backbone's renderer. I've a small issue though. In the addOne function, I've used view.render() instead of view.render().el, what was taught in the tutorial.

The view doesn't render with view.render.el(). Any explanation?

```
$(function(){
Todos = new TodoList.Collections.Todos;
TodoList.Views.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    events: {},
    initialize: function(){},
    template: _.template('<li> <%= task %></li>'),
    render: function(){
        var todo = this.model.toJSON();
        return this.template(todo);
    }
});

TodoView = TodoList.Views.TodoView;

TodoList.Views.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#todo_app"),
    events: {
        "submit form#new_todo": "createTodo"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll','render');
        Todos.bind("add", this.addOne);
        Todos.bind("reset", this.addAll);
        Todos.bind("all", this.render);
        Todos.fetch();
    },

    addOne: function(todo){
        var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
        this.$("#todo_list").append(view.render());
    },

    addAll: function(){
        Todos.each(this.addOne);
    },

    newAttributes: function(event){
        var new_todo_form = $(event.currentTarget).serializeObject();
        return {
            dog: {
                name: new_todo_form["todo[task]"],
                age: new_todo_form["todo[done]"]
            }
        };
    },

    createTodo: function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var params = this.newAttributes(e);
        Dogs.create(params);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to `console.log` each of the components of the call the output would be similar to the following:

```
view // your view object which contains methods and properties - BackboneView
render  // a method of the view object - a function
el // a property of the view object - an HTMLElement
```

So, you can't call `el` because it's only a property, in fact it's an `HTMLElement` object. In your code you are `returning html`. If you were to chain the the calls via view.render().el you would have to return the instance using the `this` keyword. When you return an `instance` you get access to all of the `instance`'s properties and methods again in one line (chainablility). So, when you return `html` you can't chain off the view object, which is why, in the demo, they return `this`.

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
    return this; // return the instance
}
```

You shouldn't return the html of the view anyway. You always want to access Backbone's html via the `el` or `$el` properties.

Answer (score 1):

`el` isn't a function, but rather the HTML that would constitute the view. Calling `render()` normally generates the HTML and stores it in the `el` property. By convention this method should return `this` allowing you to reference the object directly (and for chaining).

So, `view.render().el` will render the element and return the HTML suitable for appending to the DOM.