# Returning 'this' from Backbone render function

Tags: backbone.js

Sometimes in tutorials I see people returning 'this' from their render function.  Is this now obsolete?

```
render : function() {

   ...


   return this;
}
```

Comment: Why would it be obsolete? A common pattern is `$(x).append(view.render().el)` and that becomes cumbersome if `render` doesn't `return this`.

Comment: I thought it may be obsolete like _bindAll() is now obsolete in most cases in Backbone.  If fact I thought it may have had something to do with automatic binding of this to other functions in the View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official document still says:

> A good convention is to return this at the end of render to enable
>   chained calls.

http://backbonejs.org/#View-render

Answer (score 0):

It is not obsolete. You want to return 'this' from your render function to enable chained calls. This means that you can use the 'el' property to manipulate your HTML. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137749/why-would-views-not-render-with-el) has a good explanation of this issue.